# Parcelable InputStream

Tags: java, android

I want to pass an InputStream from one activity to another. So I've tried using Intent, and the putExtra method.but I have no idea how to add the input stream into the Intent

```
mmInStream; //my Input Stream
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
.
.
.
intent.putExtra("NAME", mmInStream);
startActivity(intent);
```

If someone has an idea about how to pass the InputStream, or even an address of some sort which could be turned into the it, he is more that welcomed to write it.

Comment: it is not possible. Why do you need to pass an InputStream ?

Comment: I need to use the same bluetooth device in different activities so i've created it's IO streams and now I'm trying to pass it to the other activity

Comment: Use the singleton class to set and get the stream. Or you can you Application class for the purpose, but not in the `Intent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not possible to send a inputstream in putextra.
You can use a cache class class to store and use data in next activity.
Like this:

```
 public class yourclassname extends Application
   {
   public static InputStream minputStream;
   public static void setinputstream(InputStream is)
 {
     minputStream=is;
  }

   public static InputStream getinputstream()
  {
      return minputStream;
   }

}
```

And use this like this :

```
       mmInStream;   
       Intent intent = new Intent(...);
      yourclassname.setinputstream(mmInStream);
```

And get this whereever you want in the application:

```
  InputStream is=yourclassname.getinputstream();
```

Comment: Nice solution, I've just found another way to solve it which is sending the device object  itself  (which is parcblable) before opening it

Comment: good that you got another way to slove it, because i use this when no option has left to store data to use in other activity.